# Automate labeling a tikz graph that is input as points from a file

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I'm taking some time today during our national quarantine (where I no longer have access to the office's non-LaTeX graphics creation software) to try to actually learn some `tikz` and to automate the process of graph creation, according to a visual format that I often use, which consists of one or more x-y plots on a single square graph, where the plots are collections of data points (line and/or scatter plots).

I have formulated a data file which is `\input` to the plot routine.  All in all, I am happy with the result, but am unable to resolve one issue... that of automating input to accomplish labeling each of the plots.

Here is where I am presently.  My input file is currently thus:

```
% The data files, written on the first run.
\begin{filecontents*}{PlotA.data}
1.33E-02    10.403432
1.33E-01    12.53108
2.66E-01    14.90265
3.99E-01    17.22483
5.31E-01    19.58292
6.64E-01    21.89876
9.20E-01    24.44624
1.20E+00    26.6708
\end{filecontents*}
\def\PlotAfile{PlotA.data}
\def\PlotAdrawoptions{red}
\def\PlotAoptions{only marks, mark=*, mark options={fill=white}}
\def\PlotAlegend{Plot A data}

\begin{filecontents*}{PlotB.data}
# COMMENT IN THIS FILE
4.35E-02    9.562436
4.35E-01    10.845494
8.69E-01    12.24356
1.30E+00    13.66974
1.74E+00    15.13008
2.17E+00    16.57845
2.61E+00    17.97894
3.04E+00    19.41534
\end{filecontents*}
\def\PlotBfile{PlotB.data}
\def\PlotBdrawoptions{densely dashed}
\def\PlotBoptions{mark options={fill=white}}
\def\PlotBlegend{Plot B data}

\begin{filecontents*}{PlotC.data}
8.57E-01    11.255013
9.99E-01    11.4804
1.14E+00    11.718
1.29E+00    11.9916
1.64E+00    12.65854
2.00E+00    13.308
2.64E+00    14.484
3.85E+00    16.8
\end{filecontents*}
\def\PlotCfile{PlotC.data}
\def\PlotCdrawoptions{blue}
\def\PlotCoptions{mark=triangle*, mark options={}}
\def\PlotClegend{Plot C data}

\begin{filecontents*}{PlotD.data}
4.28E+00    17.56312023
5.71E+00    20.21127914
7.14E+00    22.85943805
8.57E+00    25.50759696
9.99E+00    28.15575587
\end{filecontents*}
\def\PlotDfile{PlotD.data}
\def\PlotDdrawoptions{thick}
\def\PlotDoptions{mark=square*, mark options={fill=yellow}}
\def\PlotDlegend{Plot D data}

\def\legendcoords{(6,10)}
\def\nplots{4}
\def\showlegend{T}% ANYTHING BUT T TURNS OFF LEGEND
\graphdim=8cm
%
\def\xaxislen{10.4}
\def\xaxisstart{-.2}
\def\xaxisinc{2}
\def\xaxismode{int}% {} OR {int}
\def\xlabeloffset{0.6cm}
\def\xlabeltext{$\hat f$}
\def\xlabeloptions{%
%     fixed,
%     use comma,
%     fixed zerofill,
     precision=1,
     1000 sep={,},
}
%
\def\yaxislen{30}
\def\yaxisstart{0}
\def\yaxisinc{5}
\def\yaxismode{}% {} OR {int}
\def\ylabeloffset{0.8cm}
\def\ylabeltext{$F(\hat f)$}
\def\ylabeloptions{%
     fixed,
%     use comma,
%     fixed zerofill,
     precision=0,
     1000 sep={,},
}
%
```

The plotting file, which creates standalone image files that I can later insert into my document is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=1pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{epigrafica}
%\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\newcounter{plotnumber}
\newlength\graphdim

\input mytikzinput

\newcommand\answer[1]{$\mathrm{\expandafter\pgfmathprintnumber\expandafter
  [\labelopts, assume math mode]{#1}}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={\graphdim/\yaxislen}, 
                    x={\graphdim/\xaxislen}]
   %axis
  \draw (\xaxisstart,{\yaxisstart+\yaxislen}) -- 
        ({\xaxisstart+\xaxislen},{\yaxisstart+\yaxislen});
  \draw ({\xaxisstart+\xaxislen},\yaxisstart) -- 
        ({\xaxisstart+\xaxislen},{\yaxisstart+\yaxislen});
  \draw (\xaxisstart,\yaxisstart) -- coordinate (x axis mid)
        ({\xaxisstart+\xaxislen},\yaxisstart);
  \draw (\xaxisstart,\yaxisstart) -- coordinate (y axis mid) 
        (\xaxisstart,{\yaxisstart+\yaxislen});
        %xticks
        \let\labelopts\xlabeloptions
        \pgfmathparse{\xaxismode(\xaxisstart}
        \let\thexllim\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathparse{\xaxismode(\thexllim+\xaxisinc)}
        \let\thexlnext\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathparse{\xaxismode(\xaxisstart+\xaxislen)}
        \let\thexulim\pgfmathresult
        \foreach \x in {\thexllim,\thexlnext,...,\thexulim}
        \draw (\x,{\yaxisstart*\graphdim/\yaxislen+1pt}) -- 
              (\x,{\yaxisstart*\graphdim/\yaxislen-3pt})
              node[anchor=north] {\answer{\x}};
        %yticks
        \let\labelopts\ylabeloptions
        \pgfmathparse{\yaxismode(\yaxisstart}
        \let\theyllim\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathparse{\yaxismode(\theyllim+\yaxisinc)}
        \let\theylnext\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathparse{\yaxismode(\yaxisstart+\yaxislen)}
        \let\theyulim\pgfmathresult
        \foreach \y in {\theyllim,\theylnext,...,\theyulim}
        \draw ({\xaxisstart*\graphdim/\xaxislen+1pt},\y) -- 
              ({\xaxisstart*\graphdim/\xaxislen-3pt},\y)
              node[anchor=east] {\answer{\y}};
  %labels      
  \node[below=\xlabeloffset] at (x axis mid) {\xlabeltext};
  \node[rotate=90, above=\ylabeloffset] at (y axis mid) {\ylabeltext};

  %plots
  \foreach\z in {1,...,\nplots}{
    \stepcounter{plotnumber}
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand\draw 
       [\csname Plot\Alph{plotnumber}drawoptions\endcsname]
       plot[\csname Plot\Alph{plotnumber}options\endcsname] 
       file {\csname Plot\Alph{plotnumber}file\endcsname}}
    \tmp node [below left] {blah};% GOES TO LAST POINT
%    attempts to use [midway, pos=...] do not avail
  }

  %legend
  \if T\showlegend\relax
    \begin{scope}[shift={\legendcoords}] 
    \setcounter{plotnumber}{0}
    \foreach\z in {1,...,\nplots}{
      \stepcounter{plotnumber}
      \edef\tmp{\noexpand\draw
        [\csname Plot\Alph{plotnumber}drawoptions\endcsname,
         text = black, yshift=\numexpr1-\z\relax\baselineskip]  
        plot [\csname Plot\Alph{plotnumber}options\endcsname] 
        (0.3,0) -- (0.0,0) -- (0.6,0)
        node[right]{\csname Plot\Alph{plotnumber}legend\endcsname}}
    \tmp;
    }
    \end{scope}
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

The current result is this:

[image]

While I can use qualifiers such as `below left`, the issue you can see (found in the section of code labeled `%plots`) is that I am trying to figure out how to place the plot's label at some arbitrary length along the plot.  What I have currently always places the label relative to the last point in the dataset.  I have tried using things like `midway` and `pos=` qualifiers, but they just move the label back to the origin.

So the question is, obviously, how to resolve the placement of the plot label.  I suppose, in the worst case, I can always have the user specify the graph coordinates where the label should go, but I thought there could be a more automatic way.

Note: for purposes of code development, I have all plots being labeled in the same fashion.  After I figure out how to resolve this issue, I will revise code to differentiate the labels of each respective plot.

Comment: Ti*k*Z does not have this built in but if you use `pgfplots` you can use `\addplot ... node[pos=x] {blah};` to put the node at some fraction `x` of the plot. Of course, if it is a priori clear that these are all linear plots, there are very simple solutions within Ti*k*Z alone available.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you.  In general, they are not linear plots. I have a hard time figuring out where `pgfplots` leaves off and `tikz` picks up.  Is it true that `tikz` lays atop `pgfplots`, much in the same way that `LaTeX` lays atop `TeX`?

Comment: No, `pgfplots` is based on Ti*k*Z. It is "just" some package that uses Ti*k*Z/pgf and specializes on plots.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Helpful!  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I would do. With `pgfplots` the whole enterprise becomes much simpler IMHO. (It may well be that I overlooked some details, if so, please let me know.)

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=1pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} % my MacTeX 2020 is still downloading
\newlength\graphdim
\input{mytikzinput}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\graphdim,
    legend style={at={(0.98,0.02)},anchor=south east},
    xlabel=\xlabeltext,
    ylabel=\ylabeltext,
    xmin=\xaxisstart,
    xmax=\xaxislen,
    ymin=\yaxisstart,
    ymax=\yaxislen]
 % this can be done in a loop but I'd really use pgf keys in the 
 % input file. if that's not acceptable I will be happy to build
 % a loop with these macros 
 \tikzset{locA/.style/.expanded={\PlotAdrawoptions,\PlotAoptions}}
 \addplot[locA]     table {\PlotAfile}
    node[midway,above,sloped]{blah};
 \tikzset{locB/.style/.expanded={\PlotBdrawoptions,\PlotBoptions}}
 \addplot[locB] 
    table {\PlotBfile}
    node[midway,above,sloped]{blah};
 \tikzset{locC/.style/.expanded={\PlotCdrawoptions,\PlotCoptions}}
 \addplot[locC] 
    table {\PlotCfile}
    node[midway,above,sloped]{blah};
 \tikzset{locD/.style/.expanded={\PlotDdrawoptions,\PlotDoptions}}
 \addplot[locD] 
    table {\PlotDfile}
    node[midway,above,sloped]{blah};
 \legend{\PlotAlegend,\PlotBlegend,\PlotClegend,\PlotDlegend}   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This uses your data file. Obviously you do not need to slope the nodes, this is just to indicate that this is possible.

You can make it a loop. (The loop would be prettier if the parameters were stored in pgf keys, but of course macros also work. Obviously `blah` can be replaced by a plot-dependent macro. And you could find out the upper bound of the loop with `\ifcsname` but you know these things better than me.)

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=1pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} % my MacTeX 2020 is still downloading
\newlength\graphdim
\input{mytikzinput}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\graphdim+1.5cm,% <- +1.5cm is an estimate of the space taken by the y labesl
    legend style={at={(0.98,0.02)},anchor=south east},
    xlabel=\xlabeltext,
    ylabel=\ylabeltext,
    xmin=\xaxisstart,
    xmax=\xaxislen,
    ymin=\yaxisstart,
    ymax=\yaxislen]
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{A,B,C,D}{
 \tikzset{loc#1/.style/.expanded={\csname Plot#1drawoptions\endcsname,
    \csname Plot#1options\endcsname}}
 \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[loc#1]     table {\csname Plot#1file\endcsname}
    node[midway,above,sloped]{blah};
  \noexpand\addlegendentry{\csname Plot#1legend\endcsname}}
 \temp}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  Let me study it.